# How to configure Sinatra app from the outside?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This is my code:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
class Front < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    settings.foo
  end
end
```

I'm running it like this:

```
app = Front.new
app.set(:foo, 'Hello, world!') // doesn't work!
app.run!
```

I want to inject that `foo` into the app somehow and pre-configure [other params](http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) before running. I'm getting:

```
undefined method `set' for #<Sinatra::Wrapper:0x007fea3729a990>
Did you mean?  send (NoMethodError)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the option in *before* initializing. The following should work:

```
Front.set :foo, 'Hello, world!'
app = Front.run!
```

I've done this in one of my projects here: https://github.com/alexdovzhanyn/odyn/blob/f6f88d68dd9738b4857c26c185829ccd1190d423/nodelauncher.thor#L7

Comment: You're not able to call `Front.new.run!`, but use `Front.run!` instead.

Comment: Edited to match your comment above